# iPhone 5C running iOS 7 does not display Contacts

Tags: ios, contacts

I have two different problems with contacts on my iPhone:

1. Some of them are duplicated
2. The new contacts are not available to see, like they doesn't exist, but if I dail the number in the contact shows up.

Does anyone know whats going on here and have a solution for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You likely have more than one contact "group".

In your case you will want to look two places.  First open the contacts app and note that using the "groups" button in the top left you will be able to 'show' a group that's not showing. That should get back the contacts that are "invisible" now.

Also navigate to 'Settings > Mail, Contacts, Calendars' and look at the "default account" in the Contacts section, which defines which "group" new contacts are stored to.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the Contacts app and tap the little arrow circle in the top left. This will sync your contacts with iCloud and should fix your issues.